# renaming subset of columns in r with paste0

Tags: r

I have a data frame (`my_df`) with columns named after individual county numbers. I *melted*/*cast* the data from a much larger set to get to this point. The first column name is year and it is a list of years from 1970-2011. The next 3010 columns are counties. However, I'd like to rename the county columns to be `"column_"+county number`.

This code executes in R but for whatever reason doesn't update the column names. they remain solely the numbers... any help?

```
new_col_names = paste0("county_",colnames(my_df[,2:ncol(my_df)]))
colnames(my_df[,2:ncol(my_df)]) = new_col_names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the subsetting within the `colnames` call.

Try `names(my_df) <- c(names(my_df)[1], new_col_names)` instead.

Note: `names` and `colnames` are interchangeable for `data.frame` objects.

EDIT: alternate approach suggested by flodel, subsetting outside the function call:

`names(my_df)[-1] <- new_col_names`

Comment: thanks Ferdinand.kraft. this solved it. there's no problem using colnames (as you noted) but the subsetting was the problem. is it not possible to replace a subset of the colnames or rownames?

working code:
`colnames(my_df)=c(colnames(my_df)[1],new_col_names)`

Comment: you can, but the correct syntax is: `colnames(my_df)[2:ncol(my_df)] <- new_col_names`

Comment: @flodel, that is much better!

Answer (score 1):

`colnames()` is for a matrix (or matrix-like object), try simply `names()` for a `data.frame`

Example:

```
new_col_names=paste0("county_",colnames(my_df[,2:ncol(my_df)]))
my_df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=rnorm(5), c=rnorm(5), d=rnorm(5))
names(my_df) <- c(names(my_df)[1], new_col_names)
```